# How to traverse through JsonArray of Integers in OpenEdge Progress 4gl?

Tags: arrays, json, openedge, progress-4gl

I have a JsonArray of Integers
example - [1000, 1001, 1002,.....,1100].

I need to traverse this JsonArray so that I can call my function one by one.

I tried

```
function Amen returns JsonObject (input code as JsonArray, input lang as char):

def var Amenities as JsonObject.
    Amenities = new JsonObject().
    Amenities:Add("Code", code).
    for first inditaal where string(inditaal.indi-nr) = string(code) and inditaal.taal-code = lang no-lock.
    end.
        Amenities:Add("Description", inditaal.inditaal-oms).

return Amenities.

end function.

define variable code as JsonArray no-undo init [10400, 10239, 10205].

def var result as JsonArray.
result = new JsonArray().

def var lineObj as JsonArray.

do i = 1 to code :length:
    lineObj = new JsonArray().
    lineObj = code :GetJsonArray(i).
    result:Add(Amen(lineObj)).
end.
```

I am unable to get integers from JsonArray code.
Is there any other way to do it?

As I am new to this language, I am unable to do so and also I'm not finding anything in the documentation.
Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an Integer extent (ABL Array) to the JsonArray, use the Add method.

To loop through the JsonArray, iterate to the JsonArray's Length and use GetInteger(i) to retrieve a single value.

```
USING Progress.Json.ObjectModel.* FROM PROPATH . 

define variable code as INTEGER EXTENT no-undo init [10400, 10239, 10205].

DEFINE VARIABLE oJsonArray AS JsonArray NO-UNDO . 
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

oJsonArray = NEW JsonArray () . 

oJsonArray:ADD (code) . 

do i = 1 to oJsonArray:length:
    message oJsonArray:GetInteger (i) .
end.
```